# When adding a line at the end of a file, the text sometimes is not written to new line

Tags: bash, text-processing

In some case when we want to append new line to file we see that actuality the new line that we append was inserted to the end of the last line

For example, here the file before append:

```
more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Now we append that:

```
echo "182.2.3.4 host_1" >>/etc/hosts
```

and we get:

```
more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6182.2.3.4 host_1
```

The maybe simplest solution is to do:

```
echo  >> /etc/hosts
```

but I will happy to get some other ideas for solution.

Comment: [Sanitizing files with no trailing newline](https://backreference.org/2010/05/23/sanitizing-files-with-no-trailing-newline/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because the original file had no newline at the end of the last line. `echo "182.2.3.4 host_1"` doesn't add one at the start (but does add one at the end, after `...host_1`), so the resulting file doesn't have one.

Because of issues like this, and because, strictly speaking, [the standard requires a "line" to end with a newline](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206), you should make sure to always have it there. Some utilities can give unexpected behaviour without the last newline (e.g. `wc -l` counts newline characters, so wouldn't count such a line as a line; and the `read` builtin returns a falsy status if it doesn't see a newline). Some editors always add it, some don't. In the ones that don't, make sure to hit enter after the last line or see if you can move the cursor to the "empty line" below it to make sure the newline is there.

Files like that could be fixed with e.g.

```
perl -i  -pe '$_ .= "\n" unless /\n$/' file-maybe-without-nl.txt
```

which should leave the trailing newline as-is if it already is there. (`awk 1 < file.txt > fixed.txt` also seems to work, but awk doesn't have a standard in-place editing feature. `sed` has, but I can't tell how to do it with it.)

Of course, you could also unconditionally add the newline with something like `echo >> /etc/hosts`, or `echo -e '\n182.2.3.4 host_1' >> /etc/hosts`, but that would add spurious empty lines in the middle if the file was correctly formatted before the addition.

A way to check for the final newline without having to read the entire line, would be to use `tail -n1` or `tail -c1` to fetch the last line (or line fragment) or just the last character. Then

```
[ "$(tail -c1 "$f")" = "" ] || echo >> "$f"
```

could be used to add it if necessary. (This relies on the command substitution eating any newlines, so its expansion is empty if the newline *is* there.) Or using `read` (which returns a falsy status if it doesn't see a newline):

```
tail -c1 file | read -r tmp || echo >> file
```

(Idea of `tail` and the whole latter command borrowed from a blog post here: https://backreference.org/2010/05/23/sanitizing-files-with-no-trailing-newline/)

Note that the carriage return character (CR) is distinct from the newline/line-feed character (LF) that is used as the line terminator on Unix-like systems. (CR+LF is used as the line terminator on DOS and Windows.)

Comment: Just to amuse @JeffSchaller, at least with GNU ed, `printf 'w\nq\n' | ed -s file.txt` also works.

Comment: sed has no standard in-place editing feature. It's a GNU sed extension. GNU awk has an in-place editing extension. Its' newer than the one in GNU sed, so less "famous".

Comment: @Kaz, it's there in e.g. FreeBSD sed too.